# How to implement : same query but different connections

Tags: delphi

I have the same query only the connections change :

```
if DataModule1.1_CONNECTION.Connected = true
then begin
DataModule1.ZAM_GESLO.SQL.Text:='select user,pwd from users where user = :a';
DataModule1.ZAM_GESLO.Params.ParamByName('a').AsString := DataModule1.LOGIN_QUERY.FieldByName('user').AsString;
DataModule1.ZAM_GESLO.Open;
cxGrid1.ActiveLevel.GridView := MYGRIDVIEW1;
end else 
if DataModule1.2_CONNECTION.Connected = true
then begin
DataModule1.ZAM_GESLO.SQL.Text:='select user,pwd from users where user = :a';
DataModule1.ZAM_GESLO.Params.ParamByName('a').AsString := DataModule1.LOGIN_QUERY.FieldByName('user').AsString;
DataModule1.ZAM_GESLO.Open;
cxGrid1.ActiveLevel.GridView := MYGRIDVIEW2;
end;
.......
```

This is a long way arround,so I was wondering if this can be done in any other optimized way so I dont have to write the same query all over again?

Comment: Do not ask if true is true, there will bo no true-er. It is connected or not connected and you can write it `if DataModule1.1_CONNECTION.Connected then` or `if not DataModule1.1_CONNECTION.Connected then`

Comment: You just have to set the connection to the query component `FooQuery.Connection := BarConnection;`

Answer (score 0):

To save duplicated code, you could add a procedure to your form

```
procedure TxForm.UseDataSet(ADataSet : TxDataSet; AUserName : String);
begin
  if ADataSet.Active then
    ADataSet.Close;
  ADataSet.SQL.Text:='select user, pwd from users where user = :a';
  ADataSet.Params.ParamByName('a').AsString := AUser;
  ADataSet.Open;
  cxGrid1.ActiveLevel.GridView := AGridView;
end;
```

**Note:**  I've used "x" in the ADataset parameter's type because I didn't know which type of dataset you're using, likewise your Form's type.

Then, you could re-write your code as

```
if DataModule1.1_CONNECTION.Connected then 
  begin
    UseDataSet(DataModule1.ZAM_GESLO,
      DataModule1.LOGIN_QUERY.FieldByName('user').AsString);
  end 
else 
  if DataModule1.2_CONNECTION.Connected then
    begin
      UseDataSet(DataModule1.ZAM_GESLO,
        DataModule1.LOGIN_QUERY.FieldByName('user').AsString);
    end;
```

Btw, it's good that you obviously wondered about duplicated code when you asked your q.  Whenever you find yourself writing essentially the same code using different objects, consider writing a procedure (or function) which contains the repetitive code and which operates on the objects as parameters.

Comment: Did I misunderstand your question?